# Redundant jeklly breadcrumb navigation issue

Tags: html, jekyll, breadcrumbs, static-site

I have this jekyll code but it's not ideal. Currently, if you visit a page with a structure of `example.com/careers/job-postings/` it comes out fine, as Home / Careers / Job Postings. But if you go back to careers, it's Home / Careers / Careers. Each one has the last child as non-linked. 
How can I get rid of the redundancy or generally improve this logic? (I grabbed most of this code from elsewhere.)

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <div class="wrap">
      {% capture url_parts %} {{ page.url | remove: "/index.html" | replace:'/'," " }}{%     endcapture %}
    {% capture num_parts %}{{ url_parts | number_of_words | minus: 0 }}{% endcapture %}
    {% assign previous="" %}
    <ol>
    {% if num_parts == "0" or num_parts == "-1" %}
        <li><a href="/">home</a> &nbsp; </li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="/">home</a></li>

    {% for unused in page.content limit:num_parts %}
        {% capture first_word %}{{ url_parts | truncatewords:1 | remove:"..."}}{% endcapture %}
        {% capture previous %}{{ previous }}/{{ first_word }}{% endcapture %}

        <li><a href="{{previous}}">{{ first_word }}</a></li>

        {% capture url_parts %}{{ url_parts | remove_first:first_word }}{% endcapture %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% unless page.title == first_word %}

        <li>{{ page.title }}</li>

    {% endunless %}

    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Off-Topic; try CodeReview.StackOverflow instead.

Comment: If you want to improve your code, you really should ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as TylerH suggested.